# android communication between devices

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, communication

I'm writing an android App which is basically finished and functions well on a single device. 
I now need to create a communication between two different machines and to send information back and forth.

the problem is that I have zero knowledge about how do this, and all the different guides didn't gave any begginers information about it.

I understood that I need to use a third party server, but couldn't find information where to purchase one, and how to communicate with it.

can you please tell me which technologies I should inquire about? what should I study? what API's should be helpful for me?

Regards,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think App Engine is the best choice for you.

[AppEngine](https://appengine.google.com/)